# External module's service instance not getting created

Tags: angular

I have an external module (`ExternalModule`) imported in my `AppModule`. The constructor of a service in my external module is not getting called. Below is my code of the two modules and the service,

```
// AppModule
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ExternalModule } from './external/external.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ExternalModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

// ExternalModule
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NewService } from './new.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    NewService
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class ExternalModule { }

// NewService
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class NewService {
    constructor() {
       console.log('New service constructed');
    }
}
```

I want the constructor of `NewService` to be called when my app loads. Find the following sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/SenalKumarage/external-module).

Will an instance get created just by registering it on the module's providers ?

According to the angular v5 documentation,

> The providers array tells Angular to create a single, shared instance of `HeroService` and inject into any class that asks for it.

Does this mean even if we register the service in the providers array, do we still need to request at least once for a singleton instance of that service to be created ?

Comment: where you called `NewService` in your app loads.

Comment: I don't want to call any method of the service. Just need the constructor to be called

Comment: ok. Now check my post.

Comment: hi, please check the answer , your service constructor get called when first time you request instance of your service , just putting it in provider list it register it and doesnt create instace of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing this line

```
  providers: [
    NewService
  ],
```

you are actually registering you service , this doesnt mean it create service instance.

It will will create instance when you request for instance of service in other service, component or directive or pipe.

so if you want to create instance of service just do like this in you application component.

```
 //app.component.ts
 constructor(
    private newservice: NewService )
```

When you register you service at approot level there is only instance of service is get created and that instance get served to all the component in application which request it.

Comment: From the doc of Angular 5 : "The providers array tells Angular to create a single, shared instance of HeroService and inject into any class that asks for it." (in NgModule). Providers on module should instanciate the singleton service

Comment: @AdrienSAULNIER - i believe instance get created when requested..can you please provide link to doc

Comment: @AdrienSAULNIER - i went through same document twice before writing my answer , it doesnt tell when instace of service get created

Comment: The documentation does tell something like that. "The providers array tells Angular to create a single, shared instance of `HeroService`", but looks like it won't create one unless it is asked at least once

Comment: @Senal - yes, because i created test code at my end to find it out

Comment: @AdrienSAULNIER - i created same code at my end , and its does as i written in my answer i.e. it create instace of service when it first time get requested , provider just register it doesnt create instance of service

Comment: @PranayRana looks like angular is creating the instance when you request it for the first time. After that even in a sibling component if you request it it will pass you the previously created instance. I have updated my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/SenalKumarage/external-module) to demo this.

Comment: @PranayRana Woh, ok D: I lived in the lie ahah ! Ty dude :)

Answer (score 0):

Import `NewService` into your app.component.ts

```
import { NewService} from './external/new.service';
```

Now add constructor inside itself like this:

```
constructor(private _newService:NewService){}
```

Comment: doesnt seems like solution

Comment: Yes, it's not the solution and I don't want to inject it into my app component

Comment: I think you should use `APP_INITIALIZER`